# The value of spark.network.timeout must be no less than the value of spark.executor.heartbeatInterval

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to increase the heartbeat interval parameter in pyspark configuration but keep getting this error. Is there any good combination of `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` interval and `spark.network.timeout` that increase the timeout value for big jobs but also make me start spark session without this error?

> IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: The value of
> spark.network.timeout=120s must be no less than the value of
> spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000s.'

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have to increase the `spark.network.timeout` value too.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior) clearly states:

> `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` should be significantly less than
> `spark.network.timeout`

It's hard to interpret "*significantly less*" but by default `spark.network.timeout` is 12X greater (120s) than `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` (10s).

Try:

```
--conf spark.network.timeout 100000 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10000
```